# Tkinter update canvas colors for a number of objects

Tags: python, tkinter

could anyone help me with this: I have a list of dictionaries, where I stock the information for future Tkinter rectangles. Once the rectangles are created, i'm trying to make them change color depending on changing "x" value, but it only works for the last created object and not for the rest of them  here is a code:

```
from tkinter import *

a = {
    "y":2,
    "len" : 4
    }


b = {
    "y":5,
    "len" : 7
    }


c = {
    "y":6,
    "len" : 8
    }


d = {
    "y":2,
    "len" : 4
    }


e = {
    "y":4,
    "len" : 12
    }


f = {
    "y":3,
    "len" : 10
    }


g = {
    "y":7,
    "len" : 10
    }


groupe = [a,d, b, c, g, e, f]

xt1 = 800
xt2= 800
yt1=720
yt2=0

master = Tk()
root = Canvas(master, width=800, height=720)
root.pack()

#Moving RedLine
def deplacer():
    global xt1, yt1, xt2, yt2
    xt1-=5
    xt2-=5
    root.coords(laser_print, xt1, yt1, xt2,yt2)
    root.after(50,deplacer)

    return

#drawing blocks

graf_dist = 0
dist_betw=0
untouched = "blue"
being_touched = "red"
touched= "gray"
block_color=untouched

for ensemble in groupe:

    graf_dist+=60
    dist_betw+=10

    xo=graf_dist+dist_betw
    yo=int(ensemble['y']*50)
    xl=xo+60
    yl=int(ensemble['len']*50)

    if xo<=xt1 and xl>xt1:
        block_color=being_touched
    elif xo<xt1 and xl<=xt1:
        block_color=untouched

    drawing_block = root.create_rectangle(xo, yo, xl, yl, fill=block_color, tag="blocks")


#draw horizontal redline
laser_print=root.create_line(xt1, yt1, xt2, yt2, fill="red")

#updating the color of the rectangles
def update_color():
    x_block=xt1+1
    untouched = "blue"
    being_touched = "red"
    touched= "gray"
    block_color=untouched   

    if xo<=x_block and xl>x_block:
        block_color=being_touched
    elif xo<x_block and xl<=x_block:
        block_color=untouched
    root.itemconfig(drawing_block, fill=block_color)
    root.after(50,update_color)

update_color()
deplacer()
mainloop()
```

Comment: ***only works for the last created object***: `xo` has the value from the last `.create_rectangle(x0, ...` and did never change. You have to loop your **created rectangles** to find a matching `xo`.  Read up on [Tkinter.Canvas.find_...-method's](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_closest-method)

Comment: Thank you, stovfl, going to try this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, you draw seven blocks, but they are all assigned to `drawing_block`. When you refer to `drawing_block` in `update_color()`, this is of course the last block.

First thing you need to do is having separate objects for each block, for example, by storing them in a list:

```
drawing_blocks = []
for ensemble in groups:
...
    drawing_blocks.append(root.create_rectangle(xo, yo, xl, yl, fill=block_color, tag="blocks"))
```

Then you need to change the `update_color()` function to test whether the laser passes each of the separate blocks and then change the color of that specific block.

Comment: Thankyou, Ronald, trying that!

Comment: In the `update_color()` function you should access the xo and xl of each individual block. I'm sure you can obtain them somehow from the block objects in the list.